# how use scroll with simpleModal plugin

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I'm using simpleModal plugin
http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/ 
when the text in the dialog is too long, I try to scroll, but the entire page is scrolling, even when using modal:true.

so I can't see the end of the dialog , I try define maxHeight - but seem with no effect.

any idea?

code:

```
 function loadDialog(Code,vrsnNum)
 {
  vrsnNum=vrsnNum-1;
  $.get(
   "/ajaxVerision.asp", 
   {Code: Code,VerisionNum: vrsnNum},
    function(data)
     {
     $(".CrnrPager").html(data);
     }
    );

  $.get(
   "/ajaxVerisionNext.asp", 
   {Code: Code,VerisionNum: vrsnNum},
    function(data)
      {
      $("#sp1").html(data);
      }
   );

  $('#basic-modal-content').modal({maxHeight: 400,autoPosition : true, position: ['20%','25%']});
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try to assign some CSS to the `modal()` call, something like this:

```
$('#basic-modal-content').modal({
    maxHeight: 400,
    autoPosition: true,
    containerCss: {
        'maxHeight' : '400px',
        'overflow' : 'auto'
    },
    position: ['20%', '25%']
});
```

In addition you also have the `dataCss` property available.

Comment: I added "width:490px; overflow-x:hidden; _height:400px; max-height: 400px; overflow-y:auto;" to the data-div style and that correct the problem, thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty safe now to use `calc` in css so this is what I'm doing

```
$('#confirmDialog').modal(
{
    dataCss: 
    {
          'maxHeight': 'calc(100vh - 10em)',   // spaces are needed
          'overflow': 'auto'
    }
 });
```

This says leave at least 10em (5em either side) above and below the dialog. Fortunately even if you resize the window this all adjusts nicely.

I'm using the `calc` function with `100vh - 10em` which means take the viewport height and subtract 1em. You can't use `100%` here because this is a nested element. Unfortunately on iOS `100vh` includes the space that is obscured by Safari's icon bar so I had to make the amount subtracted 10em to ensure it is always visibile.

Note: I'm using the `dataCss` which adds style attributes to the content and not the wrapper. This means if you have a border that the border will be fixed and the content scroll nicely inside it.

Read this for a better understanding of `vh` on iOS: https://github.com/scottjehl/Device-Bugs/issues/36